# Is it possible to move /home mount point from one disk to the disk where / mount point is?

Tags: partition, move-partition

I have this setup of Ubuntu 18:
two identical disks. In one (`sda`) there is `/` and `/boot/efi`. In the other disk (`sdb`) there is `/home`.

The free space in `sda` is enough to hold what is used in `sdb`.

I would like to move `/home` to `sda`. It could be the same partition `sda1`, or it could be a new partition, say `sda3`.

Here is what gparted shows me:

[image: disks partitions]

Is it possible to make this moving?

I don't know if what I'm saying makes sense, but my plan is:

- resize sda1 to say, 200GB
- format the empty space in sda to ext4 (creating sda3)
- copy the content of sdb1 to sda3
- tell linux that /home now is in sda3 (this part I have no idea how to do)

Comment: this is always a very very bad idea to have not separated /home partition ideal is having separated /home /var /usr and / + /tmp as minimal segmentations etc... specially for /home it is always a good idea to have it on its own separated disk ....depending on your usages risk is more or less acceptable.  In your case the best choice is to make a sda3 to your new home keeping it separated even it is on same physical disk.

Comment: Do you think making an sda3 for /home besides being best is easier too?

Comment: Very similar to this which is moving to another drive, but a move is a move. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Another alternative is to split /home & your data. I keep /home in / (with just the mostly hidden files) and everything else in data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `sudo` or `su` instead of logging in directly, you will still lock the home directory and you will be unable to umount `/home`. If you cannot login directly, you should probably use a live CD.

Another option however would be:

- create a user `safemove`, with a home directory `/tmp`.
- add `safemove` to the sudoers file with `visudo`
- log in with `safemove` at the terminal (typically control-shift-f1). This will prevent the creation of the complete graphical desktop under `/tmp`.
- make sure everybody else is logged off.
- as `safemove`, `sudo -s`
- `mkdir /mnt/home`
- `umount /home`
- `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/home`
- copy `/mnt/home/*` to `/home` if you do not want a separate partition, including ownership and permission flags.
- remove `/home` from `/etc/fstab`
- take a deep breath and reboot.

You should now have everything in `/dev/sda1`. Check this first before removing the user `safemove`.

If you are going to mess with `/home`, it is always good to have, at least temporarily, a userid that does not have its homedir under `/home` and that can `sudo` and/or `su`.

If you want to

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you should login as root in order to avoid locking `/home`. Then you can unmount `/home`, remount it elsewhere (let’s suppose `/mnt`), then copy all files from `/mnt` to `/home` preserving the permissions (`cp -rp /mnt/* /home`). Then edit `/etc/fstab` and change where you mount `sdb1`.

If you can’t login as root, use a Live CD.

However, having a separate `/home` enables you to reformat `/` if you want to change the OS keeping your personal file. But surely, nearly 1TB for the OS is quite important.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you mean "If you can't login as root, use a Live CD."?
When the data currently in sdb1/home will be moved to sda?

Comment: Some systems lets you connect as root, some others expect you to connect as a normal user, then from the opened session, use `sudo` to elevate your priviledges. Try login as root, then we will see.

Comment: Then, logged as root, proceed as inducated ( `umount /home`, then `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`…..)

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer "If you can login as root, use a Live CD." You probably mean the inverse, "If you can't login as root, use a Live CD."

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

my `/etc/fstab` for example is

```
UUID=800e924a-a869-4152-9503-9d9cfecbd16e                /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=4f3da85a-71a9-4f6e-bc5f-dfd23a880b08                /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=1FAB-9515                                           /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e0791b9e-b620-4274-9857-78389b10f5a5   /data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

# my /data is a 15tb hardware raid-5, comes in as /dev/sda1
# my root partition comes in as /dev/sdb3, with /boot and /boot/efi as sda2 and sda1.
```

I do not have `/home` as mounted as a separate partition.  If it was you would see it as an entry in `/etc/fstab` as such, it will be quite obvious.

In your case you want to make `/home` on your root partition, so here is what I would do

- your existing home is mounted as a separate partition, reference it from `/etc/fstab`
- `mkdir /newhome`
- `cp -rp /home/* /newhome/`
- `umount /home`
- `rmdir /home`
- `mv /newhome /home`
- remove the mount point of `/home` from your `/etc/fstab`; that's all that really needs to happen if you want to have `/home` on your root `/` partition {which is already being mounted in /etc/fstab as `/`)

**note:** the umount command will likely result in failure if logged in as a user where that mount will inherently be busy.  So if you log in as root, whose home directory is `/root` and not under the mounted `/home` you should have no problem.

**note2:** you don't even need to use the `/home` folder convention, simply change the location of user folders in `/etc/passwd` to wherever you want those user account *home* folders to reside.  For example all my user accounts on my server specified in `/etc/passwd` have home folders under `/data/users/<name>`.  I do have a `/home` folder present, but it has nothing in it.  My `/data` is mounted in `/etc/fstab` and is a raid-5 bunch of disks making 10 tb worth of space.

Comment: The difference between your approach and the other answers is that you copy before mount. Do you know if it makes any difference?

Comment: not sure what you are asking... you can't copy from something or to something unless it is mounted.  What I posted above was to illustrate the steps involved to get the concept across.  I don't get where the other answers were coming from (didn't really read them in depth) but they seemed to be making it more difficult than it needed to be.

Comment: his original `/home` is on a different partition (and already mounted) which he doesn't want.  So make any folder (i.e. newhome) on the root partition as a place holder, because you can't use the syntax "/home" just yet its already in use.  Get everything copied off the existing /home (which is on that different partition thats unwanted)  and onto the root partition under `/whatever`, then umount existing `/home` and move `/whatever` (i.e. newhome)  syntactically into its place.  hope that helps.